# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() while filling CodeIgniter MVC table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm new to PHP/CodeIgniter and am making a table that retrieves the count of values from Mysql within a particular timeframe.

Controller Class:

```
public function totallistings($slug='')
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $main['page_title']=$this->config->item('site_name').' - Listings Reports';
        $main['header']=$this->adminheader();
        $main['footer']=$this->adminfooter();
        $main['left']=$this->adminleftmenu();  
        $content='';
        $fdate = $this->input->post("fdate");
        $content['tdate'] = $tdate = $this->input->post("tdate");
        if(isset($fdate)){
            $content['fdate'] =$fdate;
        }else{
            $content['fdate'] = '';
        }
        if(isset($tdate)){
            $content['tdate'] =$tdate;
        }else{
            $content['tdate'] ='';
        }
        $main['content']=$this->load->view('crm/reports/totallistings',$content,true);
        $main['jsArray'] = array('public/assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js' );  
        $main['cssArray'] = array('public/assets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.css','public/assets/css/reports.css');
        $this->load->view('crm/main',$main);
        $content['groupedleads'] = $this->leads_model->get_listingstatus($fdate,$tdate);
    }
```

But this gave me the a Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error on my webpage:

[image]

Basically I want to have it as something like this, where you just pass the start date and end date, and it returns a table with each status_to value count:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the data into the array *before* you load the view or the value `groupedleads` won't exist inside the view.

In your `totallistings()`-method, move the last line:

```
$content['groupedleads'] = $this->leads_model->get_listingstatus($fdate,$tdate);
```

and put it before you load the view:

```
$content['groupedleads'] = $this->leads_model->get_listingstatus($fdate,$tdate);
$main['content'] = $this->load->view('crm/reports/totallistings',$content,true);
...
```

Comment: So I tried this and the error went away, but the output is not showing up correctly. I get the following output https://imgur.com/a/5nyo5pD

Comment: @JayVijayModi - That's a completely different issue. If this answer solved the issue in your question, please accept it. If you have some other issue, then you need to post a new question with all the necessary information about that specific issue (example data, expected result etc.) We would need to know what your data looks like and you need to explain the logic and so on.

Comment: Hey, so I created another question if you could kindly check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69514573/table-data-not-showing-correctly-in-codeigniter-table